# Firebase Cloud Function listUser get 1000+ users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 20 * * *')
    .timeZone('Asia/Seoul') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
    .onRun((context) =>
    {
        var allUsers = [];
        return admin.auth().listUsers()
            .then(function (listUsersResult)
            {
                listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord)
                {
                    // For each user
                    var userData = userRecord.toJSON();
                    allUsers.push(userData.uid);
                    console.log(allUsers);
                });
                //res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(allUsers));

            }).then(function ()
            {
                allUsers.forEach(function (elem)
                {
                    db.ref(`Data/${elem}/Enter`).update({ test: 0, test2: 0 });
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error)
            {
                console.log("Error listing users:", error);
                //res.status(500).send(error);
            });

    });
```

I want to modify the database value that has the uid of all users as the key after getting uid through listUser(), but **listUser()** has **1000** max. If there is a good way to get uid of all users, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK supports pagination to cycle through all the registered user accounts.  Follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).  You will need to use the API to cycle through batches of 1000 or less.  The code sample provided in the documentation illustrates this:

> ```
> function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
>   // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
>   admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
>     .then(function(listUsersResult) {
>       listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
>         console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
>       });
>       if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
>         // List next batch of users.
>         listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
>       }
>     })
>     .catch(function(error) {
>       console.log('Error listing users:', error);
>     });
> }
> // Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
> listAllUsers();
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answer I want all user uids over 1000

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the previous correct answer. You can also use recursion to return all user records (`UserRecord[]`).

```
import * as FAdmin  from 'firebase-admin/lib/auth'

export const findUnusedUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return listAllUsers().then(allUsers => {
     return allUsers
  })
})

const listAllUsers = (nextPageToken?: string, accumulatorUsers: FAdmin.auth.UserRecord[] = []): Promise<FAdmin.auth.UserRecord[]> => {
  return admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      const users = [...accumulatorUsers, ...listUsersResult.users]
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        return listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken, users)
      } else {
        return users
      }
    })
}
```